# A Calculus problem in GRE math sub test

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(t)}{\sin^3(t)+\cos^3(t)}$$

I tried to use $x=\tan(t)$ to transform but it's really a mess..

Comment: Where did you find this?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Use symmetry about $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (or equivalently the substitution $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-u$) to show that your integral is the same as $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^3 t}{\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t}\,dt$.

But the sum of the two integrals is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: ...I'm so stupid... Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. It is natural to look for a computational solution, which in this case is feasible but thoroughly unpleasant. The difference between us is only that I have seen instances of this trick before.

Comment: haha, so modest

Comment: Hello, user. What do you think the answer will become if you change the exponent 3 into a general n?